# Select timeline in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, timeline, mysql-5.5

This is my MySQL table.

```
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
|   element | status      | hour                |
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
|        18 | Available   | 2020-01-19 14:23:49 |
|        18 | Unavailable | 2019-09-13 18:19:47 |
|        18 | Available   | 2019-09-13 18:18:49 |
|        18 | Unavailable | 2019-09-09 08:22:45 |
|        19 | Available   | 2019-09-07 19:13:56 |
|        19 | Available   | 2019-09-03 18:13:49 |
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Normally the timeline of rows in this MySQL table for each element `status` is unavailable / available.

But it happened that for element number 19 the timeline of rows in `status` is available / available :

```
+----------+-------------+---------------------+
| element  | status      | hour                |
+----------+-------------+---------------------+
|       19 | Available   | 2019-09-07 19:13:56 |
|       19 | Available   | 2019-09-03 18:13:49 |
+----------+-------------+---------------------+
```

is this means anomaly.

I need to intercept these cases that is, all the rows for each element `status` when the timeline is available / available.

How to do resolve this ?

Please can you help me ?

**#Edit 01**

```
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---------+
|   element | status      | hour                |   ID    |
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---------+
|        18 | Available   | 2020-01-19 14:23:49 |   6     |
|        18 | Unavailable | 2019-09-13 18:19:47 |   5     |
|        18 | Available   | 2019-09-13 18:18:49 |   4     |
|        18 | Unavailable | 2019-09-09 08:22:45 |   3     |
|        19 | Available   | 2019-09-07 19:13:56 |   2     |
|        19 | Available   | 2019-09-03 18:13:49 |   1     |
+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---------+
```

Comment: to avoid this its the best option to put element,status as unique fields in that specific table

Comment: @Zeljka I need the history for each element if add unique fields you lose the timeline. Thanks

Comment: What is your DB version?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel **5.5.62 MySQL version** on remote host

Comment: how the records are ordered? are there any other columns in the table like autoincrement ID? because for element `18` for example, the third timestamp is before the second one. same for element `19`, so how to distinguish the order here?

Comment: @mitkosoft On the MySQL table I have **autoincrement ID** and the order is for `hour` DESC

Comment: @Golia, then could you please update your description with real data.

Comment: @mitkosoft Please see **#Edit 01** on my first question. This situation is real.data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your originally published sample data you can use a sub query to take a look at the next and previous status then test

```
select s.element,s.hour,s.`status`
from
(
select t.*,
(select concat(t1.status,',',t1.hour) from t t1 
where t1.element = t.element and t1.hour < t.hour
order by t1.element,t1.hour desc limit 1) prev,
(select concat(t1.status,',',t1.hour) from t t1 
where t1.element = t.element and t1.hour > t.hour
order by t1.element,t1.hour limit 1) nxt
from t
) s
where s.status = substring_index(s.nxt,',',1) or
        s.status = substring_index(s.prev,',',1)
;
```

Comment: Thank you but I have error on `[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 't.element' in 'where clause'`

Comment: You didn't give your table name so I used t - substitute your table name.